# Phonegap 3.5.0 not loading local javascript files first time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm having a weird problem in PhoneGap 3.5 in iOS 7.1 (both simulator and device). A very similar (perhaps identical) problem happens in FireFox in MacOSX.

When I click on a jQuery-defined button that invokes a JavaScript function it fails because the function is not defined. If I load Safari's debugger and view the page - the `<javascript>` line for the included function is missing from `<head>`.

But if I hit the 'reload' icon in the Safari debugger then all JavaScript files are loaded and the functions are defined. So - this tells me the files are all there.

The same happens in FireFox - the first time the page is loaded no console messages appear; after reload they work fine.

It smells like a race condition or load order issue of some sort. But if it is load order- why wouldn't JavaScript throw an error?

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>ABR Practice Examination2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css load");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before qm-demos.css load");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jqm-demos.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before cordova.js load");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before index.js load");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before DicomStudy.js load");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/DicomStudy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Before ABRUtils.js load");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ABRUtils.js"></script>

</head>
```

So - the first time the page is loaded - none of the console messages are displayed in the console. If I reload - all are displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: I prefer loading cordova.js first. Also, make sure you are waiting for deviceReady to fire before doing anything with cordova/plugins. And remove all of your console.log's.

Comment: Arg. It was something very dumb. I had copied my javascript files from another (working) application and there were two index.js files in two different folders - and their contents were completely different. Once I put in the correct file everything worked properly. Sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528269/js-and-css-is-not-detects-when-new-page-loads

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like

1. You may not have compiled properly and the wrong cordova.js is being loaded
2. deviceReady is not properly defined, so the page doesn't know to start