# js and css is not detects when new page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In our phonegap(3.4) application we are using jquery load function for navigation. It will navigate but that page js and css files are not detect from index.html file. so we need to attach it on top of every page and if we are navigate some page by js function so with that we need to get js file by jquery getScript method. Is there any other easy way to do this.
this is index.html code

```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html>             <head>                  
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">                      
>     <title>index        
>     </title>                      
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">                          
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
> user-scalable=no" />                                           
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">                              
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">                                  
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobilestyle.css">                                                                   
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">                                   
> 
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>                                
> 
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>                         
> 
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>                                         
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>                                         
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DBDatabase.js"></script>                                         
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DBDatabase.js"></script>                                                                            
>     <script src="js/index.js"></script>                                                                              
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){var Path = "www/";}
>     </script>                                                     </head>             <body>                  
>     <div data-role="page" id="container" data-disable-page-zoom="true">                          
>       <div id="mainContainer">                                           
>       </div>                  
>     </div>                                  </body> </html>
```

Comment: Have a common `<head>` section with all your js and css files inside a separate html file. Then import this html file in every other file

Comment: can you send me code example because i am doing same as you said, so i can see what error i did

Comment: you should post your code first so we can help you.

Comment: now guide me for next page navigation also which no need to attach extra js and css with that file or within function using $.getScript, its urgent

Comment: you have just some html pages?

Comment: can you pls explain i am not understanding

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. It had been fixed when I change it was UTF-8 without BOM. Check your js files, all of them must be same data type. Usually they are UTF-8 Without BOM

Comment: from where i need to remove it , from index.html or any other also. Your issue solved or not.... is it effective solution

Comment: use notepad++ for choose it. Open files with it, you will encoding type of file under Encoding menu.
https://www.phpbb.com/kb/images/585_encoding.jpg